# HOW TO Create new databases or database instances on the application for each user?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, partitioning, multi-tenant

As you know when you have an application like a blog, users can post articles, galleries, create static pages, editors edit them...

You have tables like:

- Articles
- Authors
- Editors
- Galleries
- Static Pages
  etc.

What if you want to create a blog service that every user can create their own blogs?

When we look again to the example above, we have to create some additional tables and fields on each table.

Some user can subscribe our service, and create their blog:

Subscriber
Blogs
    subscriber_id
Authors
    blog_id
Editors
    blog_id
Galleries
    blog_id
Static Pages
    blog_id

And you have to check on every request that if the user has that blog, is authorized etc. etc.

As you see this is extremely complicating a simple blog software.

Instead of this, is there any app or cloud service that I can use it's api on my software and create a new fresh clean database instance with the apps sql and when my users register and start to use their service?

I am very stuck on this now... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can still allow users to create their own blogs using one database. If you want to utilise a separate API you will have to manage the users logon details to that service and the associated keys (which may or may not be a breach of the API's terms of service)

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to learn how to program and design databases. In this particular case it may be worth your time to search for open source software that does something similar to what you want - see how they do it. A basic book on database design/normalization would definitely be beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused.

1. You want to have a blog service where people can sign up and get there own blog site?
2. You want to put each new blog user on a separate database?

Unless you are planning on having hundreds of thousands of users You really just need 1 database to start.

I don't think you'll need to create extra tables or fields. All your tables that link to the author should already have an author_id field or a joining table.

So..
The bloggers, when registering, will be put into authors.

Authors will contain there ID.

All other tables will relate to that id either through an id field or joining table. So if you selected from articles, galleries, ect... 
you would simply do

SELECT * FROM articles WHERE author_id=1234

Comment: This is the best approach. Basically what you want is that the *access* to posts is limited by the user that created them. i.e. the currently logged-in user should only be allowed to edit his/her own posts. That way, you can still assign 'admin' users that are allowed to edit/delete posts from *any* user, e.g. to moderate posts. To *view* only the posts of a specific user, you may pass the blog-user via the url (e.g. www.mydomain.com/posts/user1/article123), or use a 'subdomain' for each user and use that for filtering (e.g. user1.mydomain.com, user2.mydomain.com)